# Horizontally scrolling a dropdown menu on a static page

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Xgzwh/2/

I have a long width drop down menu that when the window is full size you can see all the content side by side, but at the moment when you make the window the content disappears off the page and becomes inaccessible.

What I want is for the drop down content to become scrollable horizontally while the rest of the page and the menu bar stays in place.

How is this accomplished?

```
<div id="top" class="bars"><a href="index.html" class="logo">

 <nav>
<ul>
  <li class="productsli"><a href="./products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
    <ul class="productsul">  
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
  <a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  http://jsfiddle.net/Xgzwh/7/

by adding:

```
.productsul{overflow:auto;}
```

and creating a class "over" that wraps around the content and has a width bigger than both the content and the containing drop-down "ul":

```
.over{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
min-width:1100px;
margin-left:60px;
paddding-right:500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="productsul">
<div class="over">
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
<a href="./products.html"><li class="procont"></li></a>
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ddenhartog Oh, you're right. Adding padding to the right side of ".over" fixes this problem. I'm updating my answer now.